# ASP.NET Web API Hosted on IIS is not working HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api

[image]Hosted the web api application on IIS,While accessing from the MVC application 
getting error .

http://localhost:12345/token.
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Comment: Web API default URL something like http://localhost:12345/api/controllername/actionname.  please share you controller code to identify the exact problem.

Comment: Hi Hafiz,
trying to login Token Based Authentication Using ASP.Net Web API.OWIN and Identity With Entity Framework.

Comment: did you use EnableCors ? as you mention you are accessing Web API from MVC app. please share some details or you working so we can figure out exact problem

Comment: Hi Hafiz, I have enabled the Cors in webApiConfig file.                                                     public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
       
            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);

       
        }
Still not able to login from the application.
Shall I need any other wen config changes , or need to install Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors ?

Comment: can you please share error details or stack trace